# Difference between togglebutton and radiobutton controls in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am a newbie to the programming. So I am always confusing the differences between these controls.Difference between Togglebutton and Radiobutton controls in Xaml?

Comment: Please explain with example is greatly accomplished?

Comment: A ToggleButton can't be linked to other ToggleButtons to make a choice in a list, RadioButton is designed for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a real example for this

**Toggle Button:** As the name suggest a button whose state can be toggled from on to off or vice-versa. For example a Switch in your home to turn a particular light on or off.

**Radio Button:** Its name comes from the concept of buttons in Radio where for first station you press first button and for second station you press second button and so forth. So you can choose from multiple options. But at a time only one will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle Button : Like you can use ON/OFF [Change between states]
Radio Button  : Select one from list [Select one from group of option]

Answer (score 0):

`ToggleButton` has two positions right and wrong, but for multiple
`RadioButton` with the same `Groupname property`, only one can be true at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If radio button and toggle button are not part of the toggle group, their behaviour is same.

If radio button and toggle button are part of the toggle group, radio buttons can’t be deselected, but toggle button can.